# success with compilation error on Function creation, why?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I tried to create this function in Oracle Apex 5, SQL Commands and it resulted in this error 'ORA-24344: success with compilation error.' Why do you think so? I'm trying to create a random generated code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_code()
    return varchar2
    AS
    code varchar2;
    BEGIN
    code := DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,100);
    return code;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error in syntax, see below

the correct syntax is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_code

    return varchar2
    AS
    code varchar2(100);
    BEGIN
    code := DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,100);
    return code;
    END;
```

original syntax with error description:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_code()
  2
  3      return varchar2
  4      AS
  5      code varchar2;
  6      BEGIN
  7      code := DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,100);
  8      return code;
  9      END;
 10
 11  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> show error
Errors for FUNCTION GENERATE_CODE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/24     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the
         following:
         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         current delete exists prior
```

Comment: You sir are marvellous! Thank you, my issue is resolved.